# How to append data to a existing document in mongodb using spark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to append data to a existing document in a collection when I'm migrating data using Spark from other sources. i searched the documentation but i didn't find any.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching this problem and I found that you can append to a document with an existing *_id* from spark dataframe to MongoDB, you can do it using:

```
MongoSpark.save(df.write.mode("append"))
```

In mode "append" the connector will append all the fields to the document with the *_id* that exists, notice that it will remove fields that will not exist in the dataframe you're writing to the database.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/eF-qdpYbFS0